# Reconhecer repetições de palavras na String

Tags: java, algoritmo, stringbuffer

Tenho um texto dentro de um `StringBuffer` e preciso verificar e marcar as palavras que aparecem mais de uma vez. A princípio utilizei uma fila circular de 10 posições, pois me interessa apenas palavras repetidas num "raio" de 10 palavras.
Vale observar que a marcação de palavras repetidas só pode ocorrer se as palavras repetidas estiverem em um raio de 10 palavras entre elas. Caso a palavras repetidas estejam a uma "distancia" de mais de 10 palavras, não devem ser marcadas.
O método `Contem` retorna `null` caso não haja repetição ou retorna a palavra que tem repetição.
`String` é apenas a variavel que contém o texto completo.

```
StringBuffer stringProximas = new StringBuffer();
String has = "";
Pattern pR = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Zà-úÀ-Ú]+");
Matcher mR = pR.matcher(string);
while(mR.find()){
  word = mR.group();
  nextWord.Inserir(word);//inserir na lista
  has = nextWord.Contem();//verifica se há palavras iguais na lista
  //um if pra verificar se has é null ou nao
  //e aqui marca a palavra repetida, se has for diferente de null
  mR.appendReplacement(stringProximas, "");
  stringProximas.append(has);
}
public void Inserir(String palavra){
    if(this.list[9].equals("null")){
        if(this.list[0].equals("null")){
            this.list[this.fim]=palavra;
        }else{
            this.fim++;
            this.list[this.fim] = palavra;
        }
    }else{
        //inverte o apontador fim para a posição 0
        if(this.inicio == 0 && this.fim == 9){
            this.inicio++;
            this.fim = 0;
            this.list[this.fim] = palavra;
        }else if(this.inicio == 9 && this.fim == 8){//inverte o apontador inicio para posição 0
            this.inicio = 0;
            this.fim++;
            this.list[this.fim] = palavra;
        }else{
            this.inicio++;
            this.fim++;
            this.list[this.fim] = palavra;                    
        }
    }
}
public String Contem() throws Exception{
    for(int i=0;i<this.list.length;i++){
        for(int j=i+1;j<this.list.length;j++){
            if(this.list[i].equals(this.list[j]) && (!this.list[i].equals("null") || !this.list[j].equals("null"))){
                //nao pegar a mesma repetição mais de uma vez
                if(!this.list[i].equals("?")){
                    this.list[i] = "?";//provavelmente será retirado isso
                    return this.list[j];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return "null";
}
```

Meu grande problema: caso eu encontre palavras repetidas, eu só consigo marcar a segunda ocorrência pois mesmo a primeira estando na fila, a variável `word` será a segunda e por causa `while` não consigo marcar a segunda.

Estou usando esse texto como exemplo:
Hoje em dia, é necessário ser esperto. O nosso dia a dia é complicado.
O método deve retornar por exemplo (coloquei como negrito aqui, mas não necessariamente é o jeito que marcar):
Hoje em **dia**, **é** necessário ser esperto. O nosso **dia** a **dia** **é** complicado.

Comment: Você pode fornecer algum código sobre os métodos `Inserir` e `Contem` e sobre as variáveis `string`, `stringProximas` e `has` para que possamos tentar replicar o funcionamento do seu código para poder te ajudar?

Comment: Dei uma editada, olha se melhorou @Victor

Comment: Como é que você inicializa a variável `list`? Não vejo com bons olhos esse `"null"` com aspas e esse `"?"`.

Comment: @Victor isso é só pra caso de teste. Não influencia muito e não será o definitivo. Já o `list` é iniciado na classe assim: `private String list[];`, lembrando que tamanho 10.

Comment: dê uma olhada na questão que postei, fiz algumas edições e agora acho que está do jeito que você necessita!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Algoritmo:

Nesta solução eu quebrei todo o texto em *tokens*. Cada *token* ou é uma palavra ou é qualquer outra coisa entre as palavras (espaços, pontuações e outros símbolos).

Então eu percorro os tokens verificando se cada um deles é uma palavra que já existe entre as últimas palavras lidas, sendo que a quantidade de últimas palavras a comparar é limitada pelo raio especificado.

Se o token corresponder a uma palavra repetida dentro do raio, eu assinalo tanto este token que estou lendo agora como também aquela palavra repetida que já estava lá.

Por fim eu percorro novamente todos os tokens, reconstruindo o texto original e marcando as palavras cujos tokens haviam sido assinalados como palavras repetidas.

## Código:

```
public static String assinalaPalavrasRepetidasEmUmRaio(String texto,
        String marcadorInicio, String marcadorFim, int qtdPalavrasRaio) {

    List<Token> tokens = new ArrayList<Token>();
    List<Token> palavrasNoRaio = new ArrayList<Token>();
    String palavraeNaoPalavraPattern = "\\p{L}+|[^\\p{L}]+";
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(palavraeNaoPalavraPattern).matcher(texto);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        Token token = new Token(matcher.group());
        tokens.add(token);
        if (token.isPalavra() && palavrasNoRaio.contains(token)) {
            palavrasNoRaio.get(palavrasNoRaio.indexOf(token)).assinala();
            token.assinala();
        }
        if (token.isPalavra()) {
            palavrasNoRaio.add(token);
        }
        if (palavrasNoRaio.size() > qtdPalavrasRaio) {
            palavrasNoRaio.remove(0);
        }
    }
    StringBuilder textoReconstruido = new StringBuilder();
    for (Token token : tokens) {
        if (token.isAssinalado()) {
            textoReconstruido.append(marcadorInicio + token + marcadorFim);
        } else {
            textoReconstruido.append(token);
        }
    }
    return textoReconstruido.toString();
}
```

#### Classe Token:

Como observado no código acima, o próprio Token sabe se ele é ou não uma palavra, e também possui um flag que indica se ele foi assinalado.

```
class Token {
    private final String texto;
    private final boolean isPalavra;
    private boolean isAssinalado;

    public Token(String texto) {
        isPalavra = texto.matches("\\p{L}+");
        this.texto = texto;
    }
    public boolean isPalavra() {
        return isPalavra;
    }
    public void assinala() {
        isAssinalado = true;
    }
    public boolean isAssinalado() {
        return isAssinalado;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return texto.hashCode();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null || !(obj instanceof Token)) {
            return false;
        }
        return texto.equalsIgnoreCase(((Token)obj).texto);
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return texto;
    }
}
```

Os métodos **hashCode** e **equals** não são consumidos diretamente pelo meu código, mas eles são usados pela implementação do Java para *list.contains* e *list.indexOf*, sendo que o *hashCode* ajuda a acelerar a busca e o *equals* é a comparação para saber se o item é igual ao que se está pesquisando.

Existem várias técnicas para fazer um *hash code* que auxilie na performance. Neste caso eu simplesmente retorno o *hash code* do texto, pois é o texto que eu comparo no *equals* para dizer se um token é igual a outro. Repare que se o *hashCode* retornar Zero para todos os Tokens, ainda assim a busca funcionará, a questão é mesmo a performance - vale a pena uma leitura aprofundada sobre *hash codes*.

#### Código consumidor:

E este é o teste unitário:

```
@Test
public void assinalaRepetidasEmUmRaio() {

  String texto = "Dia! É bom ser esperto, não é mesmo? O nosso dia a dia é complicado.";

  String esperado = "Dia! [É] bom ser esperto, não [é] mesmo? O nosso [dia] a [dia] é complicado.";

  String obtido = ProcessadorTexto.assinalaPalavrasRepetidasEmUmRaio(texto, "[", "]", 5);

  assertEquals(esperado, obtido);
}
```

Repare que são detectadas como repetidas mesmo as palavras com captalização diferente (***"É"*** e ***"é"***), o que era uma deficiência da minha primeira resposta, trazida à minha atenção pela resposta do *@mgibsonbr*. Quem faz o truque aí é o método *Token.equals* que é usado para verificar se o token já está na lista de palavras (*palavras.contains(token)*).

Repare ainda que a primeira palavra ***"dia"*** e a última palavra ***"é"*** não foram assinaladas porque suas repetições mais próximas estão a uma distância superior ao raio especificado.

## Sobre as expressões regulares utilizadas:

A expressão regular (*regex*) que usei para encontrar cada palavra *unicode* é **[\p{L}+](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)** pois o simples **\w+** em Java se perde com palavras acentuadas.

E a regex que eu usei para obter todo o resto que não é palavra foi a negação da outra expressão, ou seja: **[^\p{L}]+**. Isso porque o Java encontra também os caracteres acentuados quando usada a regex *non word* **\W+**.

E para obter todos os tokens de uma vez (palavras e não palavras) eu usei ao mesmo tempo as duas expressões regulares separadas pelo símbolo **|** (*pipe*), que pode ser etendido como "um ou outro", por exemplo: *X|Y* = *"encontre tanto X quanto Y"*.

Answer (score 16):

## Solução:

Usando expressões regulares dá pra resolver com um código bem expressivo, pequeno e com poucos *if*s - na verdade **apenas 1 *if* e apenas 1 *loop***:

```
public String assinalaRepetidas(String texto, String marcadorInicio, 
                                            String marcadorFim, int qtdPalavrasAnalisar) {

    String palavraInteiraPattern = "\\p{L}+"; 
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(palavraInteiraPattern);
    Matcher matcher = p.matcher(texto);

    ArrayList<String> palavras = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> palavrasRepetidas = new ArrayList<String>();
    
    while (matcher.find() && palavras.size() < qtdPalavrasAnalisar) {
        
        String palavra = matcher.group();

        if (palavras.contains(palavra) && !palavrasRepetidas.contains(palavra)) {
            texto = texto.replaceAll(
                    String.format("\\b%s\\b", palavra), 
                    String.format("%s%s%s", marcadorInicio, palavra, marcadorFim));

            palavrasRepetidas.add(palavra);
        }
        palavras.add(palavra);
    }
    return texto;
}
```

**E isso é tudo! Fim.**

Abaixo, alguma explicação e também o código consumidor.

## Explicando a solução:

Eu usei expressão regular obter cada palavra no texto, ignorando espaços, parênteses, símbolos, vírgulas e outras pontuações que não sejam palavras de verdade. A expressão regular para fazer isso em Java em um texto com acentuação (usando [unicode UTF-8](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop)) é **\p{L}+**.

No mesmo loop que eu obtenho as palavras encontradas pela expressão regular, eu já substituo a palavra repetida por ela mesma, envolvendo-a pelos marcadores.

O código consumidor (teste unitário) ficou assim:

```
@Test
public void assinalaPrimeirasPalavrasRepetidas() {
  String texto = "Hoje em dia, é necessário ser esperto. O nosso dia a dia é complicado.";
  String esperado = "Hoje em [dia], é necessário ser esperto. O nosso [dia] a [dia] é complicado.";
    
  assertEquals(esperado, new AnalisaTexto().assinalaRepetidas(texto, "[", "]", 10));
}
```

Apesar de a pergunta descrever que quer apenas as 10 primeiras palavras, o exemplo de resultado esperado parece considerar todas elas. Então eu adicionei uma assinatura que dispensa o "raio" de palavras a analisar:

```
public String assinalaPalavrasRepetidas(String texto, String marcadorInicio, String marcadorFim) {
    return assinalaRepetidas(texto, marcadorInicio, marcadorFim, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
}
```

Usando este outro método, como mais de 10 palavras são analisadas, o *"é"* também é identificado como repetido:

```
@Test
public void assinalaTodasPalavrasRepetidas() {
  String texto = "Hoje em dia, é necessário ser esperto. O nosso dia a dia é complicado.";
  String esperado = "Hoje em [dia], [é] necessário ser esperto. O nosso [dia] a [dia] [é] complicado.";
    
  assertEquals(esperado, new AnalisaTexto().assinalaPalavrasRepetidas(texto, "[", "]"));
}
```

Por fim, observe que usei expressões regulares também na hora de substituir as palavras pelos seus equivalentes assinalados. Observe a *regex* no método `texto.replaceAll`. Do contrário, uma parte de outra palavra que coincidisse também seria assinalada. Por exemplo, em *"ser servidor"* seria assinalado *"[ser] [ser]vidor"*.

O teste que comprova a eficácia deste pequeno cuidado é:

```
@Test
public void assinalaApenasPalavraInteira() {
    
    String texto = "Hoje em dia, pode ser necessário servir ao ser esperto.";
    String esperado = "Hoje em dia, pode [ser] necessário servir ao [ser] esperto.";
    
    assertEquals(esperado, new AnalisaTexto().assinalaPalavrasRepetidas(texto, "[", "]"));
}
```

Comment: Melhor resposta até agora, simples e cobre todos os pontos! Eu só sugeriria usar um `Set` em vez de um `List`, não faz diferença se o texto e/ou `qtdPalavrasAnalisar` for pequeno, mas se ambos forem grandes a solução passa de quadrática para linear (pelo menos no caso de muitas palavras não repetidas). Nesse caso, a condição do `while` teria de ser adaptada, é claro.

Comment: @Caffé o problema do raio de 10 palavras é que na sua solução só está sendo analisado as 10 primeiras palavras da string e não um raio de 10 a partir de cada palavra.

Comment: as palavras têm que ser marcadas se elas forem repetidas em um raio de 10 palavras, mais que isso não podem ser marcadas

Comment: @Pacíficão Você acaba de explicar um problema muito claramente. Que tal atualizar a pergunta para que ela fique com esta clareza? Considere também desmarcar a resposta como aceita para que a pergunta possa voltar a atrair respostas, ou ainda considere postar uma nova pergunta.

Comment: @Caffé alteração feita na pergunta e já desmarquei como aceita. Ainda assim, espero que você consiga me solucionar essa dúvida, pois sua resposta foi a mais completa que obtive.

Comment: @Pacíficão Publiquei uma nova resposta com este "novo" requisito pois ao fazer do zero acabou saindo um código completamente diferente e iria descaracterizar esta resposta aqui.

Answer (score 10):

Decidi reimplementar do zero. Os motivos:

- Não depender de implementações customizadas de lista;
- Não depender de `String`s com valores especiais e arbitrários;
- Não precisar de números *hardcoded* ou matemática complicada;
- Não precisar de expressões regulares aonde uma abordagem mais simples resolve;
- Delegar ao próprio Java determinar o que é uma letra ou não de acordo com a sua implementação do padrão Unicode.

E aqui está o resultado. Comentários explicativos no código:

```java
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * @author Victor
 */
public class BuscaPalavras {

    private static final Locale PT_BR = new Locale("PT", "BR");

    public static Set<String> palavrasRepetidas(int raio, String texto) {
        // Palavras repetidas dentro do raio já encontradas. Usa um Set para eliminar duplicatas automaticamente.
        Set<String> palavrasRepetidas = new LinkedHashSet<>(50);

        // Lista contendo as últimas palavras encontradas. O tamanho máximo da lista é igual ao raio.
        List<String> ultimasPalavras = new LinkedList<>();

        // Usa para guardar a plavra que está se formanado a medida que os caracteres são lidos.
        StringBuilder palavra = null;

        // Transforma o texto todo em um array.
        char[] caracteres = texto.toCharArray();
        int tamanho = caracteres.length;

        // Itera cada posição do array até uma depois da última (importante).
        for (int i = 0; i <= tamanho; i++) {
            // Se o caractere i do texto for uma letra, acrescenta ele no StringBuilder.
            // Se estiver na posição depois da última, não entrará no if e seguirá para o else-if.
            if (i < tamanho && Character.isLetter(caracteres[i])) {
                // Cria o StringBuilder caso a palavra esteja começando agora.
                if (palavra == null) palavra = new StringBuilder(20);
                palavra.append(caracteres[i]);

            // Caso contrário, se uma palavra acabou de ser encerrada...
            } else if (palavra != null) {
                // Retira do StringBuilder e converte para maiúsculas.
                String novaPalavra = palavra.toString().toUpperCase(PT_BR);

                // Se for uma das últimas palavras de acordo com o raio, acrescenta na lista de palavras repetidas.
                if (ultimasPalavras.contains(novaPalavra)) palavrasRepetidas.add(novaPalavra);

                // Faz a lista de últimas palavras andar.
                if (ultimasPalavras.size() >= raio) ultimasPalavras.remove(0);
                ultimasPalavras.add(novaPalavra);

                // Terminou a palavra. Volta para null para que outra palavra se inicie depois.
                palavra = null;
            }
        }
        return palavrasRepetidas;
    }

    // Para testar o método palavrasRepetidas.
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String texto = "O rato roeu a roupa do rei de Roma e a rainha roeu o resto."
                + " Quem mafagafar os mafagafinhos bom amafagafigador será."
                + " Será só imaginação? Será que nada vai acontecer? Será que é tudo isso em vão?"
                + " Será que vamos conseguir vencer? Ô ô ô ô ô ô, YEAH!"
                + " O pato faz Quack-quack!"
                + " Quem é que para o time do Pará?";

        System.out.println(palavrasRepetidas(10, texto));
    }
}
```

Saída do método `main`:

```
[A, ROEU, SERÁ, QUE, Ô, QUACK, O]
```

Comment: esse não é o objetivo. Não é simplesmente pegar as palavras que se repetem. Necessito que a palavra seja marcado no texto original. Estou dando uma editada na pergunta.

Comment: Será este um [Problema XY](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1202/6077)?

Comment: @Patrick não.. o problema é claro. É marcar palavras que se repetem em um texto.

Answer (score 10):

O próprio código é explicativo. Basicamente o que fiz foi:

1. Criar uma lista com as palavras repetidas;
2. Percorrer essa lista e buscar cada palavra da lista no texto original;
3. Trocar a palavra por ela mesma mas com a marcação.

Fiz a marcação no texto com `<b></b>` ao redor das palavras repetidas.

Tendo a lista das repetidas fica fácil, pois a função `replace()` faz quase todo trabalho: busca as palavras no texto original e troca pela marcação.

**Principal**

```
Ideone ide = new Ideone();
StringBuffer texto = new StringBuffer("Hoje em dia, é necessário ser esperto. O nosso dia a dia é complicado.");
List<String> palavrasRepetidas = ide.pegaRepetidas(texto);

String saida = texto.toString().replace(palavrasRepetidas.get(0), "<b>"+palavrasRepetidas.get(0)+"</b>");

for (int i=1; i < palavrasRepetidas.size(); i++) {
  saida = saida.replace(palavrasRepetidas.get(i), "<b>"+palavrasRepetidas.get(i)+"</b>");
}
System.out.println(saida);
```

**pegaRepetidas()**

```
/**Retorna uma lista com as palavras que aparecem mais de uma vez no texto*//
private static List<String> pegaRepetidas(StringBuffer texto) {
    String textoFormatado = texto.toString().replaceAll("[,.!]", ""); //Retira pontos e vírgulas
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(textoFormatado);

    List<String> palavrasRepetidas = new ArrayList<>();

    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String palavra = st.nextToken();
        if (contaPalavra(palavra, textoFormatado) > 1) { // Se palavra aparece mais de uma vez
            if ( !palavrasRepetidas.contains(palavra) ) { // Se ela ainda não se encontra na lista de repetidas
                palavrasRepetidas.add(palavra);
            }
        }
    }

    return palavrasRepetidas;
}
```

**contaPalavras()**

```
/** Retorna o número de vezes que a 'palavra' aparece no 'texto' */
private static int contaPalavra(String palavra, String texto) {
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(texto);
    int count = 0;
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        if (st.nextToken().compareTo(palavra) == 0) {
            count++;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

Veja funcionando no ideone: http://ideone.com/n8xLlo

Answer (score 8):

Não sou muito bom em java, então aceito correções neste código, 
porém acho que cheguei no resultado que você deseja:

Veja ele rodando aqui no Ideone:

> http://ideone.com/8YvDnp

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

enum TokenKind
{
    WordSeparator,
    Word
}

class Token
{
    int _start;
    int _end;
    String _text;
    TokenKind _kind;

    public String getText()
    {
        return _text;
    }

    public void setText(String value)
    {
        _text = value;
    }

    public void setStart(int value)
    {
        _start = value;
    }

    public void setEnd(int value)
    {
        _end = value;
    }

    public int getStart()
    {
        return _start;
    }

    public int getEnd()
    {
        return _end;
    }

    public TokenKind getKind()
    {
        return _kind;
    }

    public void setKind(TokenKind value)
    {
        _kind = value;
    }
}

class LinearRepeatSearchLexer
{
    StringBuffer _text;
    int _position;
    char _peek;

    public LinearRepeatSearchLexer(StringBuffer text)
    {
        _text = text;
        _position = 0;
        _peek = (char)0;
    }

    public Token nextToken()
    {
        Token ret = new Token();
        char peek = PeekChar();

        if(isWordSeparator(peek))
        {
            ret.setStart(_position);
            readWordSeparator(ret);
            ret.setEnd(_position - 1);
            return ret;
        }
        else if(isLetterOrDigit(peek))
        {
            ret.setStart(_position);
            readWord(ret);
            ret.setEnd(_position - 1);
            return ret;
        } 
        else if(peek == (char)0)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            // TODO: 
            //  caracteres não identificados
            //  ou você pode simplificar o readWord
            return null;
        }
    }

    void readWordSeparator(Token token)
    {
        char c = (char)0;
        StringBuffer tokenText = new StringBuffer();
        while(isWordSeparator(c = PeekChar()))
        {
            tokenText.append(c);
            MoveNext(1);
        }
        token.setText(tokenText.toString());
        token.setKind(TokenKind.WordSeparator);
    }

    void readWord(Token token)
    {
        char c = (char)0;
        StringBuffer tokenText = new StringBuffer();
        while(isLetterOrDigit(c = PeekChar()))
        {
            tokenText.append(c);
            MoveNext(1);
        }
        token.setText(tokenText.toString());
        token.setKind(TokenKind.Word);
    }

    boolean isWordSeparator(char c)
    {
        // TODO: outros separadores aqui
        return c == ' ' ||
            c == '\t' ||
            c == '\n' ||
            c == '\r' ||
            c == ',' ||
            c == '.' || 
            c == '-' || 
            c == ';' || 
            c == ':' ||
            c == '=' ||
            c == '>';
    }

    boolean isLetterOrDigit(char c)
    {
        // TODO: outras letras aqui
        return (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') ||
            (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') ||
            (c >= '0' && c <= '9') ||
            (c >= 'à' && c <= 'ú') ||
            (c >= 'À' && c <= 'Ú') ||
            c == '_';
    }

    char PeekChar()
    {
        if(_position < _text.length())
            return _text.charAt(_position);
        return (char)0;
    }

    void MoveNext(int plus)
    {
        _position += plus;
    }
}

class LinearRepeatSearch
{
    StringBuffer _text;
    int _radius;

    public LinearRepeatSearch(StringBuffer text, int radius)
    {
        _text = text;
        _radius = radius;
    }

    public LinearRepeatSearch(String text, int radius)
    {
        this(new StringBuffer(text), radius);   
    }

    public List<Token> getRepeatedWords()
    {
        // ler todos os tokens
        ArrayList<Token> ret = new ArrayList<Token>();
        ArrayList<Token> readed = new ArrayList<Token>();
        LinearRepeatSearchLexer lexer = new LinearRepeatSearchLexer(_text);
        Token token = null;
        while((token = lexer.nextToken()) != null)
        {
            if(token.getKind() == TokenKind.Word)
                readed.add(token);
        }

        // localizar repetições a partir do raio
        // PERF:
        //      este laço pode ser melhorado em termos de performance
        //      pois há comparações repetidas aqui
        int size = readed.size();
        for(int x = 0; x < size; x++)
        {
            Token a = readed.get(x);
            for(int y = Math.max(0, x - _radius); y < size && (y - x) < _radius; y++)
            {
                if(x == y) continue;
                Token b = readed.get(y);
                if(a.getText().equals(b.getText()))
                {
                    ret.add(a);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return ret;
    }
}

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        // your code goes here

        StringBuffer input = new StringBuffer("Hoje em dia, é necessário ser esperto. O nosso dia a dia é complicado.");
        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
        LinearRepeatSearch searcher = new LinearRepeatSearch(input, 10);
        List<Token> spans = searcher.getRepeatedWords();
        int listSize = spans.size();
        int position = 0;
        for(int x = 0; x < listSize; x++)
        {
            Token item = spans.get(x);
            output.append(input.substring(position, item.getStart()));
            output.append("<b>");
            output.append(item.getText());
            output.append("</b>");
            position = item.getEnd() + 1;
        }
        if(position < input.length())
        {
            output.append(input.substring(position));
        }
        System.out.println(output.toString());
    }
}
```

Resultado do código:

> Hoje em **dia**, **é** necessário ser esperto. O nosso **dia** a **dia** **é** complicado.

Answer (score 7):

Uma solução bastante simples*, usando [`split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) e dois conjuntos:

```
public static String marcarRepetidas(String s, String prefixo, String sufixo) {
    Set<String> palavras = new HashSet<String>();
    Set<String> palavrasRepetidas = new HashSet<String>();

    // Acha o conjunto de palavras repetidas
    for ( String palavra : s.split("[^a-zA-Zà-úÀ-Ú]+") ) {
        palavra = palavra.toLowerCase();
        if ( palavra.length() > 0 && palavras.contains(palavra) )
            palavrasRepetidas.add(palavra);
        palavras.add(palavra);
    }

    // Marca cada uma dessas palavras no texto (envolvendo-as num prefixo e sufixo)
    for ( String palavra : palavrasRepetidas )
        s = s.replaceAll("(?<![a-zA-Zà-úÀ-Ú])(?iu)(" + palavra + ")(?![a-zA-Zà-úÀ-Ú])",
                         prefixo + "$1" + sufixo);

    // No Java 8 é mais simples (uma única chamada do replaceAll):
    // String juncao = String.join("|", palavrasRepetidas);
    // s = s.replaceAll("(?<![a-zA-Zà-úÀ-Ú])(?iu)(" + juncao + ")(?![a-zA-Zà-úÀ-Ú])",
    //                  prefixo + "$1" + sufixo);

    return s;
}
```

[Exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/bFSugp). Esse `replaceAll` no final merece uma explicação: antes de substituir uma palavra no texto, é importante se certificar que ela é mesmo uma palavra, e não uma **substring** de outra palavra. Para isso usei dois *lookarounds* negativos, um para ver se ela não é precedida de uma letra, e outra para ver se não é sucedida. O `(?iu)` é para ignorar a capitalização, e o grupo de captura é para que a palavra seja substituída pela versão marcada mas sem alterar sua capitalização. Exemplo:

> Hoje em dia, é necessário ser esperto. O nosso dia a dia é complicado. Zé. diafragma. Dia. É. Dia.

Saída:

> Hoje em **dia**, **é** necessário ser esperto. O nosso **dia** a **dia** **é** complicado. Zé. diafragma. **Dia**. **É**. **Dia**.

* Essa resposta tem como objetivo a simplicidade, não a eficiência; um método "manual" (i.e. onde cada chamada custosa da API - como as regexes - fosse substituída por um loop explícito e então otimizado), se aproveitando do `StringBuilder`, etc poderia ter melhor performance, se esse requisito for importante no seu caso particular.

Comment: Excelente ponto o da capitalização! Este detalhe me escapou. Minha resposta sofre do problema de não identificar que *"é"* é igual a *"É"*. E embora identificar seja simples usando Regex, ainda tem a questão de substituir *"É"* por *"[É]"* em vez de substirui por *"[é]"*. Ou seja: vai algum código a mais ainda pra resolver o problema. Quanto ao que você mencionou de *(?i)* não ser eficiente, experimente *(?iu)* (unicode). Veja: https://blogs.oracle.com/xuemingshen/entry/case_insensitive_matching_in_java

Comment: @Caffé Funcionou perfeitamente! Resposta atualizada

Answer (score 5):

Olá. Eu fiz uma implementação bem simples.

Essencialmente as palavras são contadas e um mapa é populado com a palavras e o número de ocorrências. Usei a palavra como chave e a quantidade como valor.

Depois eu varri o mapa, sobrescrevendo as palavras que ocorrem mais de uma vez.

Em java 8 o código ficaria mais limpo e, com certeza, a implementação pode ser melhorada.

Veja o código:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;


public class WordCount {
    Map<String, Integer> counter = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new WordCount().count();
    }

    private void count() {
        String string = "Hoje em dia, é necessário ser esperto. O nosso dia a dia é complicado.";

        StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(string, " .,?:"); //caracateres que não interessam

        while (token.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String s = token.nextToken();
            count(s);
            System.out.println(s);
        }

        System.out.println(counter);
        print(string);
    }

    private void count(String s) {
        Integer i = this.counter.get(s);
        this.counter.put(s, i == null ? 0 : ++i);
    }

    private void print(String s) {
        for (Entry<String, Integer> e : this.counter.entrySet()) {
            if (e.getValue() > 0) {
                s = s.replaceAll(e.getKey(), String.format("<b>%s</b>", e.getKey()));
            }
        }

        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Ok, ok, ok, não é Java...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use utf8::all;

my %conta;
my $s="Hoje em dia, é necessário ser esperto. O nosso dia a dia é complicado.";

for($s=~ m{(\w+)}g ) { $conta{$_}++ }
$s =~ s{(\w+)}{ if($conta{$1}>1){ "<b>$1</b>"} else {"$1"}}eg;

print $s;
```

Comment: Isso não responde a pergunta, a dúvida é em Java.

Comment: Perl, regex inside :D hehe.

Comment: Isto não fornece uma resposta à pergunta. Para criticar ou solicitar esclarecimento de um autor, deixe um comentário abaixo da publicação dele.

Comment: [Esta resposta está sendo discutida no meta.](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2465/respostas-na-linguagem-errada-devem-ser-exclu%C3%ADdas)

Comment: Desfiz a exclusão (que se deu pela fila de análise) porque, repito, [a resposta está sendo discutida no meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2465/respostas-na-linguagem-errada-devem-ser-exclu%C3%ADdas).